# Best practice for getRefreshedUserItems

Tags: yodlee

On the [data extracts](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Extract_Procedures) page Yodlee describes best practices for using getRefreshedUserItems but I think there are a few more details there that should be shared:

Is the 1 minute recommendation just in place to mitigate having to deal with large amounts of returned data?  Is it within reason to only perform the polling for refreshed accounts every 5 minutes instead?

Say I do set up my process to retrieve refreshed items every 5 minutes as previously described, but my process fails to run during one of the iterations.  If I leave it alone does that mean for 24 hours there are a few items I will have failed to pick up the refresh for?  If so, how are others handling this?  Recording a record of the timestamp of each successful communication with getRefreshedUserItems or perhaps iterating their local cache of Financial institutions that haven't been synced in more than 24 hours and retrieving updates for those as a one off communication?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for keeping the limit as 1 minute is because of high number of refreshes, at current point of time you may not have high number of users but in future it may become higher.

Coming to your question about handling failure use cases- Say one of your job fails to fetch the items for that particular instance(passed duration in request), then you can have records of all such requests(which failed to get those items) and you can have a follow up job every hour which will trigger request for all the failed durations. This way you won't missed any items and keep data in sync with Yodlee.